# Discord.py multi-line input

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that accepts multi-line input, so that it can execute a python code. My code is the following:

````
@bot.command(name="python", help="executes python script")
async def python(ctx, *args):
    try:
        with Capturing() as output: #Capture output
            exec(" ".join(args).replace('"', "'"))
        # send captured output to thread
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send("```\n{}\n```".format(e)) # Send error message
````

The thing is that this function can only take one-line input like:

```
b!python a=1;print(a)
```

However, I want to make the discord.py bot take this type of message:
An example of a complete message is the following:

```
b!python
a = 1
print(a)
```

I want to accept a multi-line input and assign it to a variable in my code and execute it:

```
code = """a = 1
print(a)
"""
exec(message)
```

I have seen some bots execute python code like that but I have no idea how to do it without using *args, in which case it only accepts one-line code. Is there a way to accept multi-line input?

Comment: How do you expect the bot to know where the input ends?

Comment: When the message ends, i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [keyword-only argument syntax](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) to indicate to `discord.py` that you want to capture all of the rest of the input as a single argument:

````
@bot.command(name="python", help="executes python script")
async def python(ctx, *, arg):
    try:
        exec(arg)
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send("```\n{}\n```".format(e)) # Send error message
````